# JSON schema for anyOf properties

Tags: json, schema

In a very simplified form, I'd like to define a JSON schema that would allow

```json
{ "a" : 1 }
```

and

```json
{ "a" : {} }
```

but not

```json
{ "a" : 1, "b" : true }
```

and not

```json
{ "a" : true }
```

I came up with the following.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties" : false,
  "anyOf" : [
    {
      "properties" : {
        "a" : {"type":"object"}
      }
    },
    {
      "properties" : {
        "a" : {"type":"integer"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "reqired" : ["a"]
}
```

However, according to https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ this doesn't work unless I remove `"additionalProperties" : false` which I definitely want. What is the right way to define this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right first the property `"reqired"` is wrong it needs to be `"required"`.

Also when you define a type of a property, you can specify one or more types at a time:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "a": {
            "type": ["integer", "object"]
        }
    },
    "required": ["a"]
}
```

You can also add additional definition in case the property a is an object and you want specific content:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "a": {
            "type": ["integer", "object"],
            "properties": {
                "b": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            },
            "required": ["b"]
        }
    },
    "required": ["a"]
}
```

So if you use https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ to validate your schema you will that following pass:

`{"a": 1}`
`{"a": {"b": 1}}`

But this will fail:
`{"a": 1, "b": 1}`
`{"a": {"b": 1}, "c":1}`